# How to strip the string to get the URL in the HTML <img>?

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing

I am writing a RSS project on iPhone. I wonder how I can strip everything inside this tag just to get the image URL:

```
<description><![CDATA[ <a href="http://vnexpress.net/gl/xa-hoi/2012/05/lat-xe-cho-25-000-lit-xang-ca-tram-nguoi-hoi-cua/"><img src="http://vnexpress.net/Files/Subject/3b/bd/67/91/Lat-xe-xang-2.jpg"></a>Trưa 7/5, chiếc xe bồn chở 25.000 lít xăng từ Hà Tĩnh vào Quảng Bình bị lật nghiêng trên quốc lộ 1A khiến xăng chảy lênh láng ra đường. ]]></description>
```

I just want to get the string

```
http://vnexpress.net/Files/Subject/3b/bd/67/91/Lat-xe-xang-2.jpg
```

Please show me how to do it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend NSXMLParser.

See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

use this method...

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

hoping this helps..

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Oh, @Ankit Srivastava answer is right. I didn't catch that is a CDATA block. Follow his answer, but I don't delete mine, couse this still can be useful to you.

You should implement NSXMLParser delegate. In your .h file `<NSXMLParserDelegate>`
And then you have to put 3 useful method in your m file.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
            {
                if (element == nil) // where element is a NSMutableString
                    element = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

                [element appendString:string];
            }
```

That doesn't matte rif you have  or  it will always call didStart end didEnd. 
Now we have ex: :

```
elementName //contains your tag name. In this case "mytag"
element // contains text beetween tags. In this case null. But in <mytag>something</mytag> element = something.
attributeDict //This is probably most important to you. That contains NSDictionary with all your parameters. In above example this is a dictionary with key: myparam and object: test
```